# Как сгрупировать одно поле многомерного массива?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив вида:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:7 [▼
    "answer_schema_id" => "1"
    "content" => "odpowiedz 1"
    "locale" => "pl"
    "points" => "3"
    "answerKey" => "1"
    "answerElementOrder" => "1"
    "image" => "5cd143beba821203428009.jpg"
  ]
  1 => array:7 [▼
    "answer_schema_id" => "1"
    "content" => "answer 1"
    "locale" => "en"
    "points" => "3"
    "answerKey" => "1"
    "answerElementOrder" => "1"
    "image" => "5cd143beba821203428009.jpg"
  ]
  2 => array:7 [▼
    "answer_schema_id" => "2"
    "content" => "answer 2"
    "locale" => "en"
    "points" => "2"
    "answerKey" => "2"
    "answerElementOrder" => "2"
    "image" => "5cd143bebcdfc405126844.jpg"
  ]
  3 => array:7 [▼
    "answer_schema_id" => "2"
    "content" => "odpowiedz 2"
    "locale" => "pl"
    "points" => "2"
    "answerKey" => "2"
    "answerElementOrder" => "2"
    "image" => "5cd143bebcdfc405126844.jpg"
  ]
]
```

Нужно получить следующий массив:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:7 [▼
    "answer_schema_id" => "1"
    "content" => [
        "pl" => 'odpowiedz 1',
        "en" => 'answer 1'    
     ]
    "points" => "3"
    "answerKey" => "1"
    "answerElementOrder" => "1"
    "image" => "5cd143beba821203428009.jpg"
  ],
1 => array:7 [▼
    "answer_schema_id" => "2"
     "content" => [
        "pl" => 'odpowiedz 2',
        "en" => 'answer 2'    
     ]
    "points" => "2"
    "answerKey" => "2"
    "answerElementOrder" => "2"
    "image" => "5cd143bebcdfc405126844.jpg"
  ]
]
```

Но так у меня получается массив только с 1м ключом.
Вот мой код:

```
$new = [];

foreach ($data as $key => $datum){
            if(empty($new)){
                $new[] = $datum;
                unset($new[0]['content']);
            }

            foreach ($new as $keyz => $item){
                if($item['answer_schema_id'] == $datum['answer_schema_id']){
                    $new[$keyz]['content'][$datum['locale']] = $datum['content'];
                }
            }
        }
```

Прошу помощи в решении данной проблемы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде бы можно как-то вот так:

```
// Исходный массив
$srcArray = [
    0 => [
        "answer_schema_id" => "1",
        "content" => "odpowiedz 1",
        "locale" => "pl",
        "points" => "3",
        "answerKey" => "1",
        "answerElementOrder" => "1",
        "image" => "5cd143beba821203428009.jpg",
    ],
    1 => [
        "answer_schema_id" => "1",
        "content" => "answer 1",
        "locale" => "en",
        "points" => "3",
        "answerKey" => "1",
        "answerElementOrder" => "1",
        "image" => "5cd143beba821203428009.jpg",
    ],
    2 => [
        "answer_schema_id" => "2",
        "content" => "answer 2",
        "locale" => "en",
        "points" => "2",
        "answerKey" => "2",
        "answerElementOrder" => "2",
        "image" => "5cd143bebcdfc405126844.jpg",
    ],
    3 => [
        "answer_schema_id" => "2",
        "content" => "odpowiedz 2",
        "locale" => "pl",
        "points" => "2",
        "answerKey" => "2",
        "answerElementOrder" => "2",
        "image" => "5cd143bebcdfc405126844.jpg",
    ]
];

// Результат
$result = [];

// Группировка
foreach ($srcArray as $item)
{
    if(empty($result[$item['answer_schema_id']]))
    {
        $result[$item['answer_schema_id']] = [
            "answer_schema_id" => $item['answer_schema_id'],
            "content" => [
                $item['locale'] => $item['content'],
            ],
            "points" => $item['points'],
            "answerKey" => $item['answerKey'],
            "answerElementOrder" => $item['answerElementOrder'],
            "image" => $item['image'],
        ];
    }else{
        $result[$item['answer_schema_id']]['content'][$item['locale']] = $item['content'];
    }
}
$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает

Answer (score 1):

По идее можно как-то вот так. Не самое красивое решение, зато один цикл, и нет доп. условий

```
       $result = [];

    foreach ($arr as $data) {
        $result[$data['answer_schema_id']]['answer_schema_id'] = $data['answer_schema_id'];
        $result[$data['answer_schema_id']]['points'] = $data['points'];
        $result[$data['answer_schema_id']]['answerKey'] = $data['answerKey'];
        $result[$data['answer_schema_id']]['answerElementOrder'] = $data['answerElementOrder'];
        $result[$data['answer_schema_id']]['image'] = $data['image'];
        $result[$data['answer_schema_id']]['content'][$data['locale']] = $data['content'];
    }
```